# How would I mix German and Icelandic diacritic characters in a single English document?

Tags: document-classes, characters, letters, letterhead

I'm trying to use the `letter-classic` class of the following version:

```
\ProvidesClass{letter-classic}[2003/03/04 v1.1]
```

The goal is to mix UTF-8 characters from German and Icelandic in an English letter. For the sake of this question I have come up with a minimal document that demonstrates my issue (store as UTF-8!):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter-classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english} %% main language of the letter

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient}
\fromname{Max Mustermann}
\fromstreet{Musterstraße 123} %% using SZ ligature
\fromtown{12345 Musterstadt}
\fromtownshort{Musterstadt}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
%% body uses mixed Icelandic characters
\begin{itemize}
    \item Icelandic characters
    \begin{itemize}
        \item þ Þ - thorn
        \item æ Æ - AE ligature
        \item ö Ö - o with dieresis
        \item á Á - a with accent
        \item í Í - i with accent
        \item é É - e with accent
        \item ú Ú - u with accent
        \item ó Ó - o with accent
        \item ý Ý - y with accent
        \item ð Ð - eth
    \end{itemize}       
    \item German characters not in the above list
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ä Ä - a with dieresis
        \item ü Ü - u with dieresis
        \item ß   - SZ ligature
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}       

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The language-specific diacritic characters come out fine in the body of the letter, but not in the letter head.

**NB:** You can find the `letter-classic.cls` of the version I use in the following [paste](http://pastebin.com/KHCxc0LN). I also found [an archive](http://www.bluemac.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/letter-classic.zip) that seems to correspond to my version of the document class, although the author's website is apparently no longer online.

I saw and read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132807/3925) and accompanying answers as well as [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization). All questions and answers I came up with so far deal exclusively with a particular single language or mixing English and whatever single other language. The problem there is that English has virtually no diacritic characters in its standardized form, so would use a subset of characters from any single language that uses the Latin script (diacritic or not).

I thought I could get away by declaring commands:

```
\newcommand{\ISL}[1]{\foreignlanguage{icelandic}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DEU}[1]{\foreignlanguage{german}{#1}}
```

and wrapping distinctly Icelandic words like Þjóðskrá and Ríkisskattstjóri as `\ISL{Þjóðskrá}` and \ISL{Ríkisskattstjóri} respectively; or distinctly German words like Musterstraße as `\DEU{Musterstraße}`. E.g. in `\fromstreet{\DEU{Musterstraße 123}}`.

However, that still doesn't allow me to use certain diacritic characters anywhere but in the body of the letter. The letter head simply doesn't accept most of these characters.

My LaTeX foo isn't exactly the strongest, but I like the format of `letter-classic` over the `letter` class that comes with several LaTeX distributions and would prefer to stick to it. So I wouldn't deem the suggestion to use the `letter` class instead as an answer, unless it provides steps to mold it into a similar shape as the `letter-classic.cls` already provides.

However, I noticed when pasting the class file that there are three lines declaring some font for later use:

```
\DeclareFixedFont{\bsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}{17.28}
\DeclareFixedFont{\nsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ssf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}{7}
```

I know `OT1` is a standard font providing the bare minimum of glyphs and that `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` lets me extend on that bare minimum. Will it be sufficient to replace `OT1` by `T1` in those instances or will this come back later to bite me in some subtle ways?

An initial experiment suggests that it fixes the immediate issue. But I don't like just patching up symptoms when the root cause may still be there; just better hidden this time.

Also: is it good form to wrap foreign words in `\foreignlanguage{}`?

Comment: I think a modern class like `scrlttr2` or the package `scrletter` might be better to use instead of that rusty thing without any maintainer information.

Comment: @Johannes_B: do they offer a similar look?

Comment: Looking at the class, it seems like it was modeled after an early version of KOMA. You should definitely try it out.

Comment: btw, input/output of the charackters has nothing to do with babel. Babel is needed for getting *Kapitel* instead of chapter and localized dates, and not to forget, the right hyphenation patterns.

Comment: Now that i read the whole question i see, that you already found the solution yourself. You can safely make the replacement.

Comment: @Johannes_B: thanks for taking the time to answer, could you put that into your answer? I'll accept it then. I was mostly hesitant as to whether this would create more problems later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the definition of the three fixed fonts to use the default encoding.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter-classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\selectlanguage{english} %% main language of the letter (not necessary)

\DeclareFixedFont{\bsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}{17.28}
\DeclareFixedFont{\nsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ssf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}{7}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient}
\fromname{Max Ðusþermann}
\fromstreet{Musterstraße 123} %% using SZ ligature
\fromtown{12345 Musterstadt}
\fromtownshort{Musterstadt}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
%% body uses mixed Icelandic characters
\begin{itemize}
    \item Icelandic characters
    \begin{itemize}
        \item þ Þ - thorn
        \item æ Æ - AE ligature
        \item ö Ö - o with dieresis
        \item á Á - a with accent
        \item í Í - i with accent
        \item é É - e with accent
        \item ú Ú - u with accent
        \item ó Ó - o with accent
        \item ý Ý - y with accent
        \item ð Ð - eth
    \end{itemize}       
    \item German characters not in the above list
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ä Ä - a with dieresis
        \item ü Ü - u with dieresis
        \item ß   - SZ ligature
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}       

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I have commented out the `\selectlanguage` instruction that's not necessary (and wrong in that place). I also added `lmodern` just to show that the declarations do what they're supposed to do: note the changed surname that uses Icelandic characters. I also used `ngerman` rather than `german`, to comply with the new orthography of German.

The idea of wrapping foreign words in `\foreignlanguage` is good.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The glyphs do not seem to be available with Computer Modern Sans Serif in OT1 encoding. The class defines three different switches, `ssf`, `nsf` and `bsf`, for small, normal and big cmss fonts, but all of them in OT1 encoding. T1 encoding (or Cork encoding) was developed to handle glyphs of western european alphabets. Simply declaring the switches in the document using `T1` should do the trick and no trip wires are to be expected.

[image: 0xCFontencodingDiacritics]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,german,english]{babel}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ssf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}{7}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    Icelandic characters
    \begin{itemize}
            \ssf
        \item þ Þ - thorn
        \item æ Æ - AE ligature
        \item ö Ö - o with dieresis
        \item á Á - a with accent
        \item í Í - i with accent
        \item é É - e with accent
        \item ú Ú - u with accent
        \item ó Ó - o with accent
        \item ý Ý - y with accent
        \item ð Ð - eth
    \end{itemize}       
    German characters not in the above list
    \begin{itemize}
            \ssf
        \item ä Ä - a with dieresis
        \item ü Ü - u with dieresis
        \item ß   - SZ ligature
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ssf}{T1}{cmss}{m}{n}{7}
    Icelandic characters
    \begin{itemize}
            \ssf
        \item þ Þ - thorn
        \item æ Æ - AE ligature
        \item ö Ö - o with dieresis
        \item á Á - a with accent
        \item í Í - i with accent
        \item é É - e with accent
        \item ú Ú - u with accent
        \item ó Ó - o with accent
        \item ý Ý - y with accent
        \item ð Ð - eth
    \end{itemize}       
    German characters not in the above list
    \begin{itemize}
            \ssf
        \item ä Ä - a with dieresis
        \item ü Ü - u with dieresis
        \item ß   - SZ ligature
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}       
\end{document}
```

The class seems to be modeled after an early version of KOMA-script letter. The current version `scrlttr2` is a very feature rich documentclass with lots of options to change the appearance.